# $C^\infty_{0}(\bar\Omega)$ dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$: the closure is necessary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

It is a fundamental result of Sobolve space that

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ or $\mathbb{R}^d_+$, then
>   $C^\infty_{0}(\bar\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.

However, in some literatures, the fact is pointed out that $C^\infty_{0}(\Omega)$ fails to dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ in some cases.

Some I would like to try some counterexamples.

My guess is take $d = 1, k = 1, p = 2$ and $\Omega = (0,1)$, i.e. claim that

> $C^\infty_{0}((0,1))$ fails to dense in $W^{1,2}((0,1))$.

But how should I proceed such an argument in a precise way?

Comment: The basic issue can be seen with constant functions, where the derivative is zero but the derivative of $C_0^\infty$ functions that approximate constant functions are highly singular near the boundary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just like Chris said in his comment, let us suppose we have a bounded Lipschitz domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, $C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ fails to approximate an arbitrary $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$-function unless you set the boundary value to be 0.

A possible argument could be constructed using the *trace theorem*. Roughly speaking,  denote $H^1(\Omega) := W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, let
$$
T: H^1(\Omega) \longrightarrow H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)
$$
be the trace operator. Suppose we prescribe a $u\in H^{1}(\Omega)$, which has a non-zero trace, leading us to the trace inequality
$$
\|Tu \|_{H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)} \leq c\| u \|_{H^1(\Omega)}
$$
Now assume we have a sequence $\{u_n\}\subset C^{\infty}_0(\Omega) \subset H^1(\Omega)$, such that $u_n\to u$ in the $H^1(\Omega)$-norm, then use trace inequality we will see the contradiction in which zero is greater than or equal to a positive number.

---

If you are not satisfying with the existence of the "non-zero trace" part, we could circumvent this by using the surjectivity of the trace operator, define its right inverse as
$$
\mathscr{I}: H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)\longrightarrow H^1(\Omega)
$$
serving like an extension of any function defined on boundary to the interior, and $T(\mathscr{I}g) = g$ for any $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, prescribe any $g\in H^{1/2}(\partial \Omega)$, say $g = 1$ on $\partial \Omega$, let $u = \mathscr{I}g$.

---

Counter-example on $\Omega = (0,1)$:

Let $u = 1\in H^1(\Omega) = W^{1,2}(\Omega)$, suppose we have a sequence $\{u_n\} \subset C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ such that 
$$
\| u - u_n\|^2_{H^1(\Omega)} = \| u - u_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} + 
\| u'_n\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)} \longrightarrow 0
$$
so for any $\epsilon>0$ we could find $N>0$ for all $n>N$:
$$
\| u - u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \epsilon, \text{ and }\; \|u'_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \epsilon
$$
By triangle inequality:
$$
\left|\| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} - \| u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\right| \leq \| u - u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \epsilon
$$
due to $\| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} = 1$, above implies
$$
1-\epsilon < \| u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < 1+\epsilon
$$
Now we would like to argue like the proof for Poincaré inequality to reach the contradiction, for 1 dimensional case it is very straightforward, for any $x\in \Omega$ we have:
$$
|u_n(x) - u_n(0)| = \left| \int^x_0 u'_n(t)\,dt\right| \leq 
\left| \int^1_0 u'_n(t)^2\,dt\right|^{\frac{1}{2}} \;
\left| \int^1_0 1^2\,dt\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}  = \|u'_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
This implies $\displaystyle\sup_{x\in\Omega}|u_n(x)| \leq \|u'_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$, therefore combining everything we have would lead us to the following:
$$
1-\epsilon < \| u_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq 
\left| \int^1_0 \sup_{t\in\Omega}|u_n(t)|^2\,dt\right|^{\frac{1}{2}}  = \sup_{x\in\Omega}|u_n(x)| \leq \|u'_n\|_{L^2(\Omega)} < \epsilon
$$
which is a contradiction, hence such sequence $\{u_n\} \subset C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ does not exist.

---

A last remark: Why would the density argument of $C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ is true for the whole space is because of the decaying property of both the function itself and the derivative of the $W^{k,p}$-functions, for something to be $L^p$-integrable on the whole space, its integration must be small outside a ball of certain size, however for bounded domain, decaying property does not hold any more unless you add the compactly-supported condition.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm wondering if it is possible to argue the specific case mentioned above($C^\infty_0((0,1))$) without trace? Preferably, a counter-example would be selfstanding.

Comment: @newbie Edited the counter-example into my answer.

Comment: It is crystal clear. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, sorry I got one more question. In the estimation of sup, is $u^n(0) = 0$ from definition of $C^\infty_0((0,1))$?

Comment: @newbie Yes, $C^{\infty}_0((0,1))$ normally denotes the compactly supported infinitely differentiable functions on $(0,1)$, the compact supportedness means it is zero on some small neighborhood of the interval's end points.

Comment: Thanks. I feel it is a bit of tricky to use $u^n(0) = 0$ since $u^n$ is actually not defined at point $0$. Probably $u^n(0+)$?

Comment: @newbie Yes, it would be the least ambiguous way to phrase like you said: $u_n(x) - \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}u_n(\epsilon) = \lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\displaystyle\int^x_{\epsilon} u'_n(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Why is the last step a contradiction ?

Comment: @Khichudi $1-\epsilon < \epsilon$?

Comment: Ok. Its a contradiction only for $0\leq\epsilon\leq1/2$.

Comment: @Khichudi It is a contradiction because of the arbitrariness of $\epsilon$ in the proof.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Why is  $\Bigl \vert \int_{\Omega} \sup_{t \in \Omega} \vert u_n(t) \vert^2 \, \mathrm dt  \Bigr \vert^{1/2} = \sup \vert u_n(x) \vert$?

Comment: @Tesla You take supreme before the integration, therefore it is a constant.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Ah yes, thanks for the reply!

Comment: Why $|u_n(x) - u_n(0)| \le ||u'_n||_{L^2(\Omega)}$ implies that $\sup_{\Omega} |u_n(x)| \le ||u'_n||_{L^2(\Omega)} $?  Sorry for the ignorance, I can't see

Comment: @RodolfoFerreiradeOliveira $u_n\in C^{\infty}_0$ so at end points it is zero.

Comment: That's true! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \cosh(x) = \tfrac{e^x+e^{-x}}2$ for $x\in (a,b)$. Then obviously $f\in C^\infty(a,b)\subset H^1(a,b)$ with $f'' = f$. Hence, for all $u\in C_0^\infty(a,b)$ we have
$$
(f,u)_{H^1} = (f,u) + (f',u') = (f,u) + [f'\overline u]_a^b - (f'',u) = (f-f'',u) = 0.
$$
Therefore $C_0^\infty(a,b)$ is not dense in $H^1(a,b)$.